# Should I add the Primary Key to a Secondary index with InnoDB?

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

for example I have this table:

`| id | name | age |`

`id` is the primary key;

this is the query:

`select id from table where age > 12 order by id desc`

Is it necessary to append `id` to the index, as:

`KEY idx (age, id)`

or is this index enough?

`KEY idx (age)`

ps: I'm using INNODB as the storage engine.

Comment: obviously, you wouldn't store age

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [Docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-index-types.html)

> In InnoDB, each record in a secondary index contains the primary key columns for the row, as well as the columns specified for the secondary index.

So no, assuming `id` is the primary key for `table`, then it will already be present on all secondary (non-clustered) indexes as well, i.e. just add `age` to the index.

Comment: does that means: in innodb, `(age)` is converted automatically to `(age, id)` ?

Comment: and does `select name from table where age > 20 order by id desc` need a `(age, id, name)` index?

Comment: No. To see for yourself, use EXPLAIN

Answer (score -3):

just that query only, and no other information. append id is much better.
append index is covered your query.